# django Cast function always sets UTC timezone

Tags: django, timezone, truncate

When I use:

```
annotate(new_datetime=Cast(
    TruncHour('old_datetime) + timedelta(days=1), output_field=DateTimeField()
))
```

TruncHour return a datetime in my timezone and after Cast, new_datetime's value will be in my timezone but with UTC tzinfo. How can I set custom tzinfo for Cast function in this case?
for more information USE_TZ = True and default timezone isn't UTC.

Comment: Please add the values of `USE_TZ` and `TIME_ZONE`.

Comment: There are different. I don't want to change them.

Comment: I'm not saying you should change them, I'm saying you should add them to the question since that information is essential to understanding how Django handles datetimes.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question.